# Is there a way to call a D function from a C or C++ main()?

Tags: d

I am working on message passing for a class, and I would like to call a D function from either a C or C++ main(). I have found many tutorials about calling a C or C++ function from a D main(), but how do you go the other way?

I have tried several resources like 
https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html and 
https://dlang.org/spec/interfaceToC.html

```
extern (C++) void foo(int num)
{
    //Does the FizzBuzz program
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
     if(i%3 == 0)
        writeln("fizz");
     if(i%5 == 0)
        writeln("buzz");
     if(i%3 == 0 && num%5 == 0)
        writeln("Fizzbuzz");
    }
}

extern (C++) void bar();
void main()
{
    bar();
}
```

and the C++ code

```
int foo(int i);

void bar()
{
    foo(100);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The D documentation explains this (with an example!) here: https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html#calling_global_d_functions_from_cpp

Answer (score 1):

For simple things, just link against libphobos:

```
$ cat main.cpp 
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int num)
{
    //Does the FizzBuzz program
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
     if(i%3 == 0)
        printf("fizz\n");
     if(i%5 == 0)
        printf("buzz\n");
     if(i%3 == 0 && num%5 == 0)
        printf("Fizzbuzz\n");
    }
}

void bar();

int main()
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}

$ cat foobar.d
extern(C++) int foo(int i);

extern(C++) void bar()
{
    foo(100);
}

$ dmd -c foobar.d

$ g++ main.cpp foobar.o -lphobos2

$ ./a.out | head
fizz
buzz
Fizzbuzz
fizz
Fizzbuzz
buzz
fizz
Fizzbuzz
fizz
Fizzbuzz
```

It does get more involved if the D code needs the D runtime to work, e.g. using the garbage collection, in which case the runtime would need to be initialized explicitly.

Comment: Since 2.079 the [garbage collector is now initialized lazily](https://dlang.org/changelog/2.079.0.html#lazy-gc-init) so that will work now seamless too, but for D module constructors a runtime initialization is still required. It's just called [`rt_init`](https://dlang.org/phobos/core_runtime.html#.rt_init) though. It might be worth pointing out that for the standard library all modules are initialized _without_ D module constructors for exactly the reason of not needing to do a `rt_init`.

Comment: I have two more questions, 1) if I wanted to go to a C main(), would I just take out the C++ in extern and 2) Is it better to use DMD or GDC?

Comment: 1) For C linkage, use `extern(C)` 2) Use the compiler that suits your needs: https://wiki.dlang.org/Compilers